# Dynamic spaces in a table

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print multiplication table and before each result I would like to add a certain amount of spaces in accordance with the number of digits of the result.

Here is what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEN 10

int len_num(int *num);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i,j;
    int space = 0;
    int multi;
    for(i = 1; i <= TEN; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j <= TEN; j++)
        {
            multi = i * j;
            space = len_num(&multi);
            printf("%*d", space, i*j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int len_num(int *num)
{
    int length = 0;
    while (*num != 0)
    {
        *num /= 10;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

For some reason the spaces do not appear.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: table]

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to review what the [field width](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) thing does.

Comment: Change `multi = i * j;` to `multi = TEN * TEN;`.

Comment: Also, there is no need for `len_num` to modify `*num`. I suggest changing the parameter type from `int *` to `int`.

Comment: By the way the name of the constant `TEN` doesn't look good. `MAX` may be better.

Comment: @IanAbbott so at first I did what you're suggesting but there are some constraints that i have to follow that this approach do not handle. First The first results (the multiplications of 1) are padded one space to the right and the result 100 attached to 90.

Comment: To be clear, you want to add 1 space to 1-digits numbers, 2 spaces to 2-digits numbers and 3 to 100? Isn't it more chaotic than a normal tabular format?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes this is exactly what i'm trying to do, it is more chaotic but this is what i've been told to do so..

Comment: Well, given the posted image, that's clearly what you are *not* supposed to do. You need to find the maximum width of each column and format the numbers accordingly. https://godbolt.org/z/Mcas4539j

Comment: @Bob__ I really did not think about it this way, thank you very much.

Comment: How about `multi = TEN * j;` `space = 1 + len_num(multi);` `printf("%*d", space, i*j);`?

Comment: @IanAbbott it closer to the result i'm seeking but the first column needs to be different.
The numbers from 1-9 have two spaces and number 10 has one space and i what i want is for the first column to have no spaces at all from the left side of the screen.

Comment: OK, how about `multi = TEN * j;` `space = len_num(multi);` `printf("%*d%s", space, i*j, j<TEN ? " " : "");`? That will remove the space from the beginning, and add a space after every column except the last one.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes this one fixed my problem ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Instead post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: Your description does not match the output you posted. In your description there should be more spaces before e.g. 100, than before e.g. 90. But in your output image it's the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a value with *n* digits to be prefixed by *n* spaces, you need to change:

```
printf("%*d", space, i*j);
```

To:

```
printf("%*d", space * 2, i*j);
```

However this will format the table in a way where columns are not aligned:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  10
 2 4 6 8  10  12  14  16  18  20
 3 6 9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
 4 8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
 5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
 6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
 7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
 8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90   100
```

If you'd like a properly formatted table, you probably need a fixed width for the values, e.g. (for a width of 5):

```
printf("%*d", 5, i*j);
```

This will yield the following output:

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40
    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50
    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60
    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70
    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80
    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90
   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

**Side notes:**

1. There's no reason for `len_num` to modify the `num` parameter, and therefore it should get it by value (`int len_num(int num)`).
2. `TEN` is not such a good name, consider to change to `MAX` (in case you might change the value 10).

Comment: thank you for your reply but my table should have only 1 space for the number is 1 digits, 2 spaces for numbers with 2 digits and 3 specifically for the last result which is 100. I just edited my post and added a picture of the table that i'm trying to print so it will be easier to undersatand.

Comment: Your description doesn't match the output you posted. But anyway isn't the 2nd output in my answer what you actually want (it looks similar to what you posted) ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks too simple:

```
printf( "%4d", i*j );
```

Comment: well, it's not. It has to to be dynamic. Using %4d will not print the right table, i added a picture of the desired table. 1 space for number with one digits 2 spaces for 2 digits number and so on.